# How do I skip/delete an item in the ItemProcessor?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to be able to delete an item while processing it if it fits a specific logic. For example, if the item doesn't contain a value I'm looking for, I don't want to that item to be written out to the file.

I'm currently using a class which implements `ItemProcessor<T,T>`.

Do I just return null?

Comment: [Returning null should be good](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html#domainItemProcessor)

Comment: So would that cause any null pointers anywhere?

Comment: AFAIK, generally, no. The null just indicates to the writer not to write

Comment: A better design would be to implement validator on your model; if validation fails, the record will be skipped and no further processing would be done.

Comment: @Barun I only know while the item is being processed if I need to skip the item or not. From what I understand of `ValidatingItemProcessor` it will only check the item and if needs to be skipped an exception is thrown and the processor will know it should skip the item. Is there something else that validates while I process an item?

Comment: @samwell No, there is nothing else that validates other than your Processors(Processors can be chained too).

Answer (score 12):

Return null from the processor like below.

```
public class ExceptionRecordValidator implements 
        ItemProcessor<yourDTO, yourDTO>{
@Override
public yourDTO process(
        yourDTOitem) throws Exception {
     if(your requested value found){
         return yourDTO ;
     }else{
         return null;
     }
  }
}
```